# How do I enable prediction when writing C# codes in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

When I write C# in Visual Studio Code, there is no prefilling with Intellisense. For example, while typing `physics.AddF` and waiting for possible results, I didn't see any results.

I found a video with instructions to fix this and followed it carefully, but I think there is something those people didn't show. Even if I delete visual studio code and do the same operations again, I encounter the same thing and it is very tiring to rewrite the codes every time

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you talking about [IntelliCode whole line completions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/visual-studio-whole-line-completions) or [IntelliSense windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)?

Comment: Did you install the C# extension? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp